making a dynamic proxy in node.js
I am trying to make a dynamic proxy that I can control with a web UI
the goal is to be able to proxy traffic going to http://localhost/server_a to something as well as http://localhost/server_b. Currently this works in theory. if I add the route to be just /. but as soon as it contains something else any service that request other resources or uses the URL for client side view routing break. is there any way I can fix this?
let last_route = null;

function resolveRoute(routes, req){
    const route = routes.find(doc => req.url === doc.route);
    if(route){
        return route;
    }else{
        if(req.headers.referer){
            if(routes.find(doc => `/${req.headers.referer.split('/')[3]}` === doc.route)){
                return routes.find(doc => `/${req.headers.referer.split('/')[3]}` === doc.route);
            }
        }else{
            console.log(req)
            return null;
        }
    }
}

const server = createServer((req, res) => {
    //get site that request is coming from

    routes.find({}, (err, docs) => {
        const route = resolveRoute(docs, req)
        let options = {};
        if(err){
            res.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            res.end('<h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1>');
        }else{
            if(route){
                last_route = route;
                options = {
                    hostname: route.hostname,
                    port: route.port,
                    path: req.url,
                    method: req.method,
                    headers: req.headers
                };
            }else{
                console.log('No route found');
                console.log(req.url)
                if(last_route){
                    options = {
                        hostname: last_route.hostname,
                        port: last_route.port,
                        path: req.url ,
                        method: req.method,
                        headers: req.headers
                    };
                }else{
                    res.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                    res.end('<h1>404 Not Found</h1>');
                }
            }

            try{
                req.pipe(request(options, (proxyRes) => {
                    res.writeHead(proxyRes.statusCode, proxyRes.headers);
                    proxyRes.pipe(res, { end: true });
                }), { end: true });
            }catch(err){
                res.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                res.end('<h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1>');
            }

        }
    })
})


Looks like you are trying to build your own http-proxy.
it will be much easier to use this (very popular) module.
Your issue is taken care of in this module by PathRewrite.
You can mix it with Express to make your life easier.
Example of changing url (with http-proxy-middleware):
const proxyMiddleware = createProxyMiddleware({
  target: 'https://someOtherDestinationHostname',
  changeOrigin: true, // In case of named-based virtual host
  pathRewrite: {
    '^/api': '', // Remove /api prefix when forwarding to the backend
  },
});
app.use('/api', proxyMiddleware);

Example of client side routing (with express):
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});


this produces the same result as what I currently have. I'm beginning to think its not possible. I think the web UI uses client side view routing so whatever is in the request URL for you browser regardless is what it uses to map the frontend with the right view. so unless I can somehow hide that in some way or mechanism this might be pointless

client side routing is aware of the full url. In libraries like react or vue you can set base path based on environment variables.
